# How to use conditional loop to iterate through items in a list?

Tags: list, loops, set, tuples

I am trying to write a very basic code that can take the input given by a user and sift through a list of positive responses to see if the user's response is part of that list.
The code below iterates for each item in the list but I do not want that, instead I want it to check all items in the list and print out something only if the input is in the list. How can I do that?

```
positive_responses = ['Good', 'Fine', 'Okay', 'Great']
user_response = input('How are you today? - ')
for each in positive_responses:
  if user_response == each:
    print('Glad to hear that')
  elif user_response != each:
    print('What can we do to help?')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can use `in` operator:

```py
positive_responses = ["Good", "Fine", "Okay", "Great"]
user_response = input("How are you today? - ")

if user_response in positive_responses:
    print("Glad to hear that")
else:
    print("What can we do to help?")
```

Prints (for example):

```
How are you today? - Great
Glad to hear that
```